# Docker Container stopped automatically in the middle of starting server

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, containers

I have an issue with a docker container...

Here is my DockerFile. I am using the tomcat image and deploying my war file to `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps`

```
FROM tomcat

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat

ADD app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war

EXPOSE 8091
```

I am using the following command to start the container

docker container run -p 8091:8091 -d imageName

After running the above command, i can see that tomcat server is starting. When it started completely, the container stopped automatically.

I have tried using different commands like below, but didn't help.

docker container run -p 8091:8091 -itd imageName

Am I using wrong parameters to run the container? Should I need to add anything  in my dockerfile?

Comment: Please paste the output from the container log so we can see what's going wrong?

Comment: Use `COPY` instead of `ADD` to deploy war file in tomcat container. Try to use the command `docker container run -d --name tomcat -p 8091:8091 <imageName>`

Comment: And also build your image first `docker image build -t hellotomcat .`

Comment: @EngineerDollery how do you get the container log ? I tried running the following command  docker logs --details containerName. It actually displayed all the server logs. In my case, it is tomcat server logs. There is not error in the logs. Container started the tomcat server successfully and after that container got stopped.

Comment: @AamirMeman Yes. I built the image before running the run command. Also i tried the command what you specified, no luck. I got the same issue. Container got stopped after starting.

Comment: Run it using `docker container run -p 8091:8091 -it imageName`, so you will get the logs in terminal itself

Comment: Have you tried to change by `COPY` instead of `ADD`.

Comment: Yes. I did tried by changing the ADD to COPY. It worked. Now i can see that tomcat server inside the container started. Thank you for your suggestion @AamirMeman

Comment: My pleasure ..Wow it's working.

Comment: @AamirMeman I have one more question on accessing the site hosted in the docker container. I have posted  as a separate question. Here is the links for that https://stackoverflow.com/q/46614520/4435358 . Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the below works for you, but just try tweaking your Dockerfile & build,run commands as per below.

```
FROM tomcat:8.0.20-jre8

COPY /app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
```

Then build and run commands as per below:

```
docker build -t app .
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8080 app
```

Comment: Yes. I did tried changing the ADD to COPY command . It worked. Now i can see that tomcat server inside the container started. Thank you for your suggestion @Akash Mishra