# Could not able to access the hosted application in Docker container from the parent host

Tags: tomcat, url, docker, networking, docker-container

I have created a Docker container with a tomcat server. I have started the tomcat server and i can see the logs that tomcat server started successfully. 
I used the following command to run the container

docker run -p 8092:8092 -dti cs2 /bin/bash

Once the tomcat server started, i tried to access the site from the parent host of the docker container.
I tried accessing the site using the following url's

//192.168.99.100:8092/

//192.168.99.100:8092/cs/wbs

I am not able to hit any above url's. I always see that site cannot be reached.

I also tried by adding my container to an newly created network like below, still no luck on accessing the site

docker run -p 8092:8092 --network my-network -dti cs2 /bin/bash

When i docker ps, i get the following container information as like in the screenshot

[Please click here to see the container information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th7qT.jpg)

Any help on this would be appreciable

Comment: Don't use the `-d` flag, so that you will know what went wrong. Start the container using `docker run -p 8092:8092 -ti cs2  /bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the container with the command: `/bin/bash`, which probably doesn't spin server. You rather should specify a command that starts the server or don't provide it at all, the image probably has default command that does just that.

If container is running you can attach to it with `docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> /bin/bash` and see what's there.

Also, on the screen, you have port `8093` exposed to the host, not `8092`.

Comment: I am actually using the /bin/bash to execute a separate shell file to start the tomcat server. If i dont follow this way, my container will get stopped automatically after the tomcat start. I corrected the port, still having the same problem.